# Cannot dismiss AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Before this is mark as duplicate or spam i would like you to know that i have tried all answers in previous questions but nothing worked

I have an AlertDialog which i want in case of failure to be dismissed. So here is my code:

```
private AlertDialog openPinDialog() {
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.rootLayout));
        one = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button);
        two = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        three = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button3);
        four = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button4);
        five = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button5);
        six = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button6);
        seven = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button7);
        eight = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button8);
        nine = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button9);
        zero = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.buttonzero);
        image1 = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        image2 = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        image3 = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
        image4 = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
        tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.changeText);
        one.setOnClickListener(this);
        two.setOnClickListener(this);
        three.setOnClickListener(this);
        four.setOnClickListener(this);
        five.setOnClickListener(this);
        six.setOnClickListener(this);
        seven.setOnClickListener(this);
        eight.setOnClickListener(this);
        nine.setOnClickListener(this);
        zero.setOnClickListener(this);
        builder.setView(view);
        builder.setTitle("Master Password");
        return builder.create();
    }
```

Where i want it to be dismissed:

```
private void retypePassword(){

        checkPinCode.append(String.valueOf(buttonClicked.getText()));
        if (count == 5){
            image1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_lens_black_24dp);
        }else if (count == 6){
            image2.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_lens_black_24dp);
        }else if (count == 7){
            image3.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_lens_black_24dp);
        }else if (count == 8){
            image4.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_lens_black_24dp);
            checkPinCode = checkPinCode.delete(0,4);
            pinCode = pinCode.delete(4,8);
            Log.e("1st Try", pinCode.toString());
            Log.e("2nd Try", checkPinCode.toString());
            if (checkPinCode.toString().equals(pinCode.toString())){
                tv.setText(R.string.second_text);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Pins match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else {
                if (openPinDialog() != null && openPinDialog().isShowing()){
                    openPinDialog().dismiss();
                }
                tv.setText(R.string.first_text);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Pins don't match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                count = 0;
                image1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_radio_button_unchecked_black_24dp);
                image2.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_radio_button_unchecked_black_24dp);
                image3.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_radio_button_unchecked_black_24dp);
                image4.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_radio_button_unchecked_black_24dp);
                pinCode.delete(0, pinCode.length());
                checkPinCode.delete(0, checkPinCode.length());

            }
        }
    }
```

onCreate Method:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        openButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button10);
        openButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openPinDialog();
            }
        });
        pinCode = new StringBuffer();
        checkPinCode = new StringBuffer();
    }
```

The result:

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beMCY.png)

Comment: `View view = LayoutInflater.from(builder.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, null, false);` Use context of the dialog builder for proper theming, Dialog has no root view yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because whenever you are calling `openPinDialog()` **It will create always new object for alert dialog**.

And you are checking your all three conditions on different object of Newly created dialog.

So it will not work, means not cancelled.

Call `openPinDialog()` only once in `onCreate()` or any other method hold reference in class level member and use that member to check your condition.

Something like,

```
Private AlertDialog pinDialog = null;


onCreate()
{
 pinDialog = openPinDialog();
}
```

And use like,

```
if (pinDialog  != null && pinDialog.isShowing()){
   pinDialog.dismiss();
}
```